# How to edit a pdf file in html5 open source without any licensed software?

Tags: c#, angularjs, html, pdf-generation, mozilla

I don't want to use pdf editors like Aspose, Debenu etc ? Preferred back end is ASP.NET MVC, C# .

I am able to load, rotate  file using mozilla pdf and angular pdf but how to persist it on the server. I can do rotation on client side very well but I need to persist the user actions like rotate, delete on the file.

I will try with iTextSharp ( AGPL license ) to Rotate or delete pages in pdf.

PDF documents are stored in Alfresco server.

My two approaches  :

1. Call Alfresco API and save the returned byte array in a file , then load this file on the html page using Mozilla PDF js or Angular pdf module

   - Store user actions like page rotate, delete etc in session and when user submits this document then do all these operations on the server side ( C# )
2. Call Alfresco API and save the returned byte array in a file , then load this file or byte array on the html page using Mozilla PDF js or Angular pdf module

   - Send a server side call every time user do any operation like rotate, delete etc.

Please suggest, performance will be a factor as well.